# Firestore trigger temporal information

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Hi so i understand firestore write triggers run out of order with respect to time. Is is possible to get timestamp information on when a write occured within the trigger functions execution context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Firebase CLI to deploy, every background function is delivered an [EventContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext) object as its second parameter.  You can use its [timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext) property.  Or, you can have the client write it into the document.

I assume something similar is available for the context object provided to code deployed by gcloud.

Comment: But @doug-stevenson, what happens if an object is written twice, in quick succession, where one trigger might hit a "cold" node. Will that cold node then populate the timestamp? My question is really: Can the first trigger look like it happened AFTER the second trigger, from inspecting the `context.timestamp`?